# How to find the minimum value and corresponding columns for each row in excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with following data

```
Name Time1 Number1 Time2 Number2 Time3 Number3 Time4 Number4 Time5 Number5

ABC   0.1    4      0.2    3     0.3    2       0.4    5      0.5   6
DEF   1.1    1      1.2    5     0.8    6       0.6    9      0.9   7
GHI   1.2    4      3.2    3     0.3    9       0.1    2      1.6   10
```

I want to find the minimum of **Time1** to **Time5** for each **Name** along with the corresponding **Number**. For **time1** corresponding number is **number1**, for **name2** is **number2** and so on. for each row it should also which of the time it chooses. For example for the above data output should be like.

```
Name Time Number
ABC   0.1  4    Time1
DEF   0.6  9    Time4
GHI   0.1  2    Time4
```

here is sample 
[image]
i will apply the formula in L for minimum time, corresponding number in M and which time in N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these formulae

[image]

```
Cell M2: =A2
Cell N2: =MIN(B2,D2,F2,H2,J2)
Cell O2: =INDEX(B2:K2,0,MATCH(N2,IF(LEFT($B$1:$K$1,4)="Time",B2:K2),0)+1)
Cell P2: =INDEX($B$1:$K$1,0,MATCH(N2,IF(LEFT($B$1:$K$1,4)="Time",B2:K2),0))
```

The formula in cell O2 and P2 is an array formula, you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to use it.

Comment: for exactly same values as above in the table that i gave, your formula doesn't work and gives N/A for the second value. it should give 7 but it gave N/A

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: the difference between my table and yours is that in my table the Time is with capital T and in your sheet it is simple time. Change the ="Time" to ="time" in the formula

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts at cell A1.
Using ";" as seperator (might have to be changed to "," depending on your settings)

Assuming the result is placed in the range (A8:D8), with A8 baring the name (in this example 'ABC') that serves as basis for the formulas:

Formula for the time of ABC (in cell B8):

```
=MIN(B2;D2;F2;H2;J2)
```

Formula for the corresponding number of ABC (in cell C8):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A8;A$2:A$4;0)+1;MATCH(B8;A2:K2;0)+1;4))
```

Formula for the remark of ABC (returns Time1) (in cell D8):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A8;A$2:A$4;0);MATCH(B8;A2:K2;0);4))
```

Drag down for the other Names

Comment: It doesn't work is not really an answer. What does the formula return? An error (which one), or the wrong value? Are the references correct, is the seperator the correct one (most people on this forum use "," as per default, whereas in my region ";" is the common one)

Comment: again, "doesn't work"  is nothing I can work with. What does the formula return? Edit your question to show the exact ranges you are using and explain clearly what is not going as expected (what do you expect, what do you get as result)? Does the remark return the correct value?µ

Comment: There is some problem with the references. first row has name and ABC starts at A2. the formula to find minimum works fine. for the other formula i am getting N/A. i have made a small excel with exactly the same values as above. e.g. the first row starts from A2 and goes till K2. I am applying formula in  L2.

Comment: its still says N/A...what is the vlaue of A8 here??? i am new to excel so having trouble applying formula.

Comment: ok, made a mistake in my comment, apologies. I've clarified the answer to explain where the formulas have to be placed. A8's value is ABC in this example. If correct, please mark the answer as "answered"

Comment: It works give correct value for minimum time but gives the wrong output for corresponding number. for the above table its gives 3,6,5 for the corresponding three numbers it should be 3,7,2. though it gives correct remark (third formula).

Comment: check again, added 2 dollar signs to make the search range absolute instead of relative

Comment: it will not work if any of the time is same as a number in the same row.

Comment: It works but now the third formula gives the wrong output. It gives correct value for  ABC but when apply to other values it just give 0.5 as numeric value

Comment: it is very difficult to continue troubleshooting without having the master file and thus without being able to see which references are used in the formula. You are currently, basically, just asking to the community to write some formulas for you, which is not really the aim. I suggest you read up on the use of the INDIRECT, ADDRESS and MATCH formulas using, for example https://exceljet.net to understand how they work. It will be more fruitfull than searching for some copy-paste info which we've trying to adapt for days now, but doesn't seem to work as we cannot access the root file.

Comment: I do not want to be rude, it's just the logical thing to do.